# DELETE statement execution cancellation in SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, delete

I ran a delete statement with wrong WHERE condition (which deletes all records from table instead of just 10 records) but during execution I found it and CANCELLED the execution in Management Studio,  which is still in query execution cancellation process (its a big table).

As far as I know if my cancellation completes successfully I don't lose any data, is my understanding correct? if not can anyone please tell me is there a way to recover deleted data from transaction log. The database is in simple recovery model.

Comment: Let query cancel completely and then run select statement to see what is status of records. You cannot do much with simple recovery

Comment: Thank you shanky for your reply. cancellation completed successfully and data looks good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it is a single statement, the operation will either succeed or fail as a whole - there is no way some of the rows will get deleted and some will remain. (And if the delete succeeds, as @Shanky suggested above, in simple recovery there is not much you will be able to do to recover the data aside from reverting to a prior backup.)

That said, do *not* get impatient and try to kill the user forcefully, or take the database offline, or shut down the service, or disconnect the network cable, or disconnect the power cord. You will need to wait for the rollback to complete - even if it's blocking other users - to be sure your data will be intact. Note that a rollback operation can take longer than the initial operation because a rollback is generally single-threaded, but the delete might have gone parallel.

In the future, you should issue a `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` prior to running ad hoc / uncontrolled / cowboy DML against a production or otherwise critical system. This way no matter when you realize your mistake, you can wait for the operation to complete and then issue a `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;` instead of madly and repeatedly slamming the stop button in SSMS. This will save you from deleting data that you can't easily recover, but there's a caveat the other way - if you did the right thing, you need to remember to `COMMIT TRANSACTION;`, since blocking the entire table while you're on lunch, home for the evening or on vacation is probably also an employment-terminating event.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer/reply. As you & @shanky said I waited for the cancellation process to complete and it did completed successfully and verified the data which is good. As you mentioned I usually do most of the time I use BEGIN Transaction, today also I have it in SSMS query window which has multiple other statements and manually selected the delete statement and executed it. Going forward I will make sure I execute all DELETE statements in NEW query window to avoid these issues. Any how thank you very much for your reply. Rao.

Comment: In addition to begin transaction, checking the @@rowcount variable after deleting or updating data to check that it within expected parameters before allowing a script to commit the transaction can help with safety.